# how to access span tag text using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to accessing html content using excel vba. Could you help me getting text values from span tag by looking the below image.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not share screenshots of code. Instead, put your code in code blocks (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)). How do you access the html code? Do you need to navigate to a webpage, is it stored in a file, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Dim oIE, oHTMLDoc, oHTMLElement
Dim sGotFromHTML

'Create internet explorer object
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'Navigate to webpage and wait for the request to complete
oIE.Navigate "https://some.url"
Do While Browser.Busy And Not Browser.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

'Navigate to element
Set oHTMLDoc = oIE.Document
Set oHTMLElement = oHTMLDoc.getElementById("lblcompanyname")

sGotFromHTML = oHTMLElement.innertext
'Also possible, different result: sGotFromHTML = oHTMLElement.innerhtml

'Unload everything
Set oHTMLElement = Nothing
Set oHTMLDoc = Nothing
Set oIE = Nothing
```

Of course, change the url to whatever you want.

After this, the string `sGotFromHTML` should contain the text fetched from the `span` element.